# Invoke a controller action by clicking on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, html

I want to have a functionality that If I mouseover and click anywhere within a specific div that it will invoke a specific controller action as if it were a link

I realize there needs to be some javascript / jquery magic in order to accomplish this but I don't even know where to begin..

Thanks

Comment: [jQuery Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), [AJAX Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX), I would start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about making an asynchronous request, you can just set `window.location` to the location of your controller action:

```
$("div").click(function () {
    window.location = "path_to_controller_action"
});
```

If you need to update the page without redirecting the user, you should make an [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path_to_controller_action",
    data: /* */,
    type: "GET", /* or post */
    success: /* execute this function when the controller action returns */
});
```